# angularJS how to user accessible url routing?

Tags: angularjs

The basic routing method like below,

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'myApp.controllers']).
 config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

I want make user can access view1 by typing url "://host/view1" on browser. but this is not work..

By using $routeProvider and $locationProvider, if user click "href=/view1" this link, then 
page routed host/view1.

But If user access directly to the url "://host/view1" it emit 404 error.
To make user can access /view1 directly by url, I have to remove html5Mode then, user can access by "://host/#/view1"

but How can I remove the # symbol!? not only just html5mode, the method user can access the page directly by typing that url.

Comment: On apache use `mod_rewrite` to route all requests to non-existing files to your `index.html`. Angular will take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Yoshi

I create .htaccess file on DocumentRoot folder and add below

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     .               /index.html              [L]
```

into .htaccess file.

that works as I expected!

ps.

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

above two lines means if the file with the specified name in the browser doesn't exist, or the directory in the browser doesn't exist then procede to the rewrite rule below

Comment: That has the same effect, yes. But you'll need to be careful, the 404 will ruin your SEO-rating. It's better to use `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: using .htaccess is not mod_rewrite? I didn't know that.. can you recommend tutorial url for mod_rewrite?

Comment: Yes, using .htaccess does not necessarily mean using mod_rewrite. You can define a lot of things in your .htaccess file, of which just one might be mod_rewrite. The ErrorDocument directive you mentioned in your answer is another. Currently I can't recommend a tutorial, but it's really not that complicated so a quick google search should yield results quickly.

Comment: How can we do this for example with an MVC .NET application?