# AngularJS - Page redirecting to some other page in angular js while trying to get parameter from url

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Here's my controller code

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
      templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofile.php',
      controller: 'ShowOrderController',
     })
```

I am passing the parameter by url.

I am trying to access this page by the url directly like this

`http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/8`

But it is redirecting me to

`http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/:UserID`

How can i get the url value in my view ?

Here is my [app.js](https://eval.in/403744)  and here is my [authCtrl.js](https://eval.in/403743)

Comment: do you have any error in console, after redirect?

Comment: I don't have any error in console

Comment: Could you post all the router configuration?

Comment: @gonzalon I have updated the entire app.js and authCtrl.js in the question. Can you pls see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your controller, it will return the object based on url value then we can get the respected value like this

```js
//it will return the object
console.log($routeParams);

//get the specific url value like this
console.log($routeParams.UserID);
   or
console.log($route.current.params.UserID);
```

Comment: If you still doesn't get means use time out function like this 
          $timeout(function() {
             console.log($routeParams);
         }, 100);

Comment: What might be the reason for redirection ??

Comment: you got the parameter value in url but redirection is your problem?

Comment: No, due to the redirection problem i can't get the url value

Comment: Please check your .htaccess file.

Comment: I am using laravel .htaccess must not the problem i guess, because it is working well in all the request...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84069/discussion-between-anjanaa-and-vijay).

Answer (score 1):

Yes possible but you have to inject the `$state` in your controller and get

if you use $state means

```
console.log($state.params.userID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
   var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/ShowOrder/:orderId', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/show_order.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrderController'
      });
}]);


sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.order_id = $routeParams.orderId;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, you have something like this in app.js:

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
  templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofile.php',
  controller: 'authCtrl',
 })
```

That means that authCtrl is assigned to this view. 
So, it's neccessary to inject routeParams to authCtrl( remember about dependency injection in javascript ) :

```
    app.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','$routeParams','$location', '$http', 'Data', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) {
    $scope.myVar = $routeParams.UserID;
    console.log('UserID: ',$scope.myVar);
    /* (...) */
}]);
```

Could you tell me, if this change, logs UserID in console? Or is empty?
If it logs, then everything works fine and you can use service to pass this variable between various controllers.

Comment: It still redirects to ':UseID`

Comment: Can you change .php file to .html ?

Comment: @cyan I have changed to .html. But still no effect

Comment: @Deena it's coma, sorry for that.

Comment: @user5071852 In what environment you use it? In some web server? maybe .htaccess is wrong or some permissions? Code look fine, but please insert also more code.

Comment: I believe that my .htaccess won't hurt this operation.. Let me show my entire js code

Comment: So you use .htaccess with this application? Could you just look and use this configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371555/angularjs-how-to-user-accessible-url-routing ?

Comment: My other views are rendering good. only this is the problem.. :(

Comment: Can u invite me to chat pls

Comment: I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Just click on the automatically move this to disucssion to chat link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83974/discussion-between-user5071852-and-cyan).

Comment: I wrote to You Sir on chat about TeamViewer. You can try to edit your post, posting more code: app.js with routeProvider and config, entire view file, entire file with ShopController and index.php file contents. That four files should help. And also how you build your project? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84062/discussion-between-cyan-and-anjanaa).