# Issue in passing url parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, url

Here is my Controller

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofdile.php',
    controller: 'renameShowCtrl',
})
```

I have a url like this

http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/8

When I click the link it redirect me to

http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/:UserID

Here is my entire app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/login', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/logout', {
                    title: 'Logout',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                    controller: 'logoutCtrl'
                })
                .when('/signin', {
                    title: 'Signup',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/signin.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/registersuccess', {
                    title: 'Dashboard',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/register-success.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/dashboard', {
                    title: 'Dashboards',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/dashboard.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/profile', {
                    title: 'Profile',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/profile.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/contact', {
                    title: 'Contact',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/contact.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/travel', {
                    title: 'Travel',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/travel.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/subscription', {
                    title: 'Subscription',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/subscription.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/invite_friends', {
                    title: 'InviteFriends',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invite_friends.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/liked_you', {
                    title: 'LikedYou',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/liked_you.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/favourites', {
                    title: 'Favourites',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/favourites.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/coins', {
                    title: 'Subscription',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/coins.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })

                .when('/forget', {
                    title: 'forget',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/forget.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/verify', {
                    title: 'verfiy',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/verify.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/verifyfb', {
                    title: 'verfiyfb',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/verifyfb.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })
                .when('/registration', {
                    title: 'verfiy',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/registration.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl'
                })


                .when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofdile.php',
                    controller: 'renameShowCtrl',

                  })
                .when('/', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/login.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                    role: '0'
                })
                .when('/invalidtoken', {
                    title: 'Login',
                    templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/invalidtoken.php',
                    controller: 'authCtrl',
                    role: '0'
                })


    }])
        .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $http) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                $http.post('CheckSession', {}).then(function (results)
                {
                    console.log(results.data);
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signin' || nextUrl == '/login' || nextUrl == '/verify' || nextUrl == '/registration' || nextUrl == '/forget' || nextUrl == '/invalidtoken' || nextUrl == '/registersuccess')
                    {
                        console.log('outpages');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (results.data == 1)
                        {
                            console.log('loggedin');
                            console.log(nextUrl);
                            ;
                            console.log('to be redirect');
                            $location.path(nextUrl);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('not logged in');
                            $location.path('login');
                        }
                    }


                });
            });
        });


        app.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.UserIDs = $routeParams.UserIDs;

});


  $scope.customNavigate=function(msg){
       $location.path("/view2"+msg)
    }
```

How can I display the parameter `8` in my view ?

Here is my [authCtrl.js](https://eval.in/403743)

Help pls

I am helping my friend [question..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31560652/5071852)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Page redirecting to some other page in angular js while trying to get parameter from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560652/angularjs-page-redirecting-to-some-other-page-in-angular-js-while-trying-to-ge)

Comment: You can't repeat your same question with another user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560652/angularjs-page-redirecting-to-some-other-page-in-angular-js-while-trying-to-ge/31562047#31562047

Comment: @Michelem We don't know how to solve this.. So, we asked another one.. Can you help us pls\

Comment: @Anitha Pass the value in the url when you change the route so you can get the value in $routeParams .just pass like this in your controller when you want to redirect to that show profile page $location.href('showprofile/'+$scope.userId);

Comment: @NareshKumar I tried directly in urll... But same error.. Can you pls explain a bit more...

Comment: @Anitha  you want to redirect to show profile in html follow this way <a href ='#/showprofile/{{userId}}'></a> If it is in controller you want to switch to show profile page follow this way  $location.href('/showprofile/'+$scope.userId);

Comment: @NareshKumar Yes i want to show their profile.. For that i plan to get the url value from url .. there i have  stuck up..

Comment: To get the params @Ajay answered $routeParams

Comment: @NareshKumar That only i am getting error :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use $routeParams to get route paramaters.

In your case, your code in controller might look like:

```
function ctrl($scope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.userId = $routeParams.UserID
    }
```

In your view use binding expression `{{userId}}`

Comment: Where should i have it ?

Comment: Use this code inside the controller with which your view is associated.

Comment: oh.. i am getting this error..`ReferenceError: getEventName is not defined`

Answer (score -1):

the right way is to pass the id parameter in url is

```
/showprofile/{UserID}
```

Comment: Should i put `{` in the url itself ?

Comment: and if you want to use this id and get value u can inject $routeparams in your controller

Comment: Event i put $routeparams, $http in my controller .. but still no solution

Comment: ok create a sample in fiddle or plunkr doenst metter and sent me the link i ll change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84055/discussion-between-anitha-and-ahmer).