# AngularJS Redirecting after displaying the parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

This is the continuation of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31560652/5071852)

So far i didn't even get the url value. But now i can able to get the url paameter but the problem is that my page is getting redirected once showing the alert

Here is my controller and route

**route**

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
  templateUrl: 'resources/views/layout/showprofile.php',
    controller: 'ShowUserCtrl'
      })
```

**Controller ;**

```
app.controller('ShowUserCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
 var b = $routeParams.UserID;
 alert(b);
    $scope.userid = $routeParams.UserID;
});
```

My View :

```
{{userid}}
```

The problem is My Url is like this

http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/18

After showing the alert `18`

It makes the url like

http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/:UserID

How can i stop the redirection .. ??

I just want this as my final url

http://192.168.1.58/myapp/#/showprofile/18

Comment: Why you're using `return false;` Try after removing that

Comment: @Vineet I have removed it thanks.. Still the problem exists

Comment: I didn't see any mistake in your code. Just run your code after commenting `alert`.  Share your idea then

Comment: @Vineet Giving alert is the end, then i try to display the value in view,, At that time only the page getting refreshes

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is because of `.run` function that i have.

After removing it works good.

Here is my `.run` function

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data, $http) {
            $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
                $http.post('CheckSession', {}).then(function (results)
                {
                    console.log(results.data);
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signin' || nextUrl == '/login' || nextUrl == '/verify' || nextUrl == '/registration' || nextUrl == '/forget' || nextUrl == '/invalidtoken' || nextUrl == '/registersuccess')
                    {
                        console.log('outpages');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (results.data == 1)
                        {
                            console.log('loggedin');
                            console.log(nextUrl);
                            console.log('to be redirect');
                            $location.path(nextUrl);
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('not logged in');
                            $location.path('login');
                        }
                    }


                });
            });
        });
```